# Stop pylab overlaying plots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, overlay

In my code, I am trying to periodically create a graph and save the graph to a file. The code looks like this:

```
import pylab as p

def simpledist(speclist,totalbugs,a):
    data = [float(spec.pop)/float(totalbugs) for spec in speclist]
    p.hist(data)
    p.savefig('/Home/s1215235/Documents/python/newfolder/' + str(a) + '.png')
```

(`a` is a counter)

However, doing this means that each new plot that is created, keeps being overlayed onto the plots before. How can I let it know that once I have saved the figure, I want it to start a new figure?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To clear the plot use [`p.clf`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=clf#matplotlib.pyplot.clf)

```
def simpledist(speclist,totalbugs,a):
    data = [float(spec.pop)/float(totalbugs) for spec in speclist]
    p.clf()
    p.hist(data)
    p.savefig('/Home/s1215235/Documents/python/newfolder/' + str(a) + '.png')
```

presuming that `p` is a `matplotlib.pyplot` or `figure` instance, also what @bernie says - that would work fine too.

**@Yann's Comment**

If you've already set up your title, axis labels etc then this will nuke all those settings. Better would be to do as he says and try

```
 p.gca().cla()
```

to preserve your hard work. Thanks Yann!

Comment: You might also want to suggest `p.gca().cla()`, so that if you have a figure title, etc and you don't want to redo all that, just update the axes. I imagine there is a more complicated way to update the data of a histogram too.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: danodonovan's answer is most likely preferable to this one from a performance standpoint.

---

You don't show how `p` is created, but I presume it is something like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
p = plt.figure()
```

In which case you'd just need to make sure you create a new figure each time. Example:

```
def simpledist(speclist,totalbugs,a):
    data = [float(spec.pop)/float(totalbugs) for spec in speclist]
    p = plt.figure() # let's have a new figure why don't we 
    p.hist(data)
    p.savefig('/Home/s1215235/Documents/python/newfolder/' + str(a) + '.png')
```

Comment: No problem. Glad you got the problem fixed.

Answer (score 2):

You can also, just turn `hold` off [(doc)](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.hold)

```
import pylab as p
ax = p.gca()
ax.hold(False)

def simpledist(speclist,totalbugs,a):
    data = [float(spec.pop)/float(totalbugs) for spec in speclist]
    ax.hist(data)
    ax.figure.savefig('/Home/s1215235/Documents/python/newfolder/' + str(a) + '.png')
```

which will clear the axes for you when ever you add a new plot.

If you have a bunch of other artists, and only want to remove the most recent one, you can use the `remove` instance functoin of artists.

```
import pylab as p
ax = p.gca()
# draw a bunch of stuff onto the axse

def simpledist(speclist,totalbugs,a):
    data = [float(spec.pop)/float(totalbugs) for spec in speclist]
    n, bins, h_art = ax.hist(data)
    ax.figure.savefig('/Home/s1215235/Documents/python/newfolder/' + str(a) + '.png')
    for ha in h_art:
        h_a.remove()
    # ax.figure.canvas.draw() # you might need this
```